# Specific line spacing in table without changing the line stretch in the text following after

Tags: tables

### I am using the knit function in R studio to make a document where I use Latex, thus I don´t know if this is the right forum. As you can see in the code underneath I use `\setstretch{1}`. However, in my RMD YAML I have

### output:
pdf_document:
toc: TRUE
toc_depth: 4
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5

The text after the table with `\setstretch{1}` also has line spacing 1 instead of 1.5. Does anyone here know how I can fix it?

```
\setstretch{1}

%% Set up counters for questions
%% 
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\newcommand*\tickbox{{\Large$\Box$}}%
\newcommand*\yesno
{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{~~}c@{}}Yes&No\\\tickbox&\tickbox\end{tabular}}%

%% we now define the questions
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{qnumber}\hfill Q.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill
    & #1
    & \small\yesno
    \\
    \addlinespace
}

    \begin{longtable}{c p{10cm} c}

        \toprule
        Nr.&Would you get vaccinated in this situation? &  \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        \question{Now, one year later, a vaccine is available. If you and enough people in Econotopia get vaccinated, fewer people will die and restrictions will be repealed. Therefore, your actions will have an effect.}
        \question{Because a lot of people took the vaccine, the authorities in Econotopia are introducing a system where vaccinated people will be able to go to restaurants, small concerts and be allowed to work from the office and meet physically at school.}
        \question{To get more people vaccinated, the authorities are now offering 100€ if you get vaccinated.}
        \question{Until now, also unvaccinated people have had the same rights of freedom as vaccinated people if they got tested for the virus 2 times a week. The authorities are now removing this possibility. Therefore, if you are not vaccinated, you cannot go to for example concerts, restaurants, or being able to go to your school or your job physically.}
        \question{Due to a new wave of hospitalization, the authorities in Econotopia introduce more powerful means to get more people vaccinated. Therefore, in addition to not having the same freedom as vaccinated people, you must pay a monthly fee of 50€ if you do not get the vaccine.}
        \question{On the news, the anchor can tell that the side effects from the vaccine can cause death for some people. Therefore, by getting vaccinated you have risks from the side effects as well as the risks from getting the virus.}
    \end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\setstretch{1}}`  (requires loading `etoolbox`).

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you very much @Bernard!

Comment: You're welcome!